# How to change google map preview background color in react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, background, styles, themes, react-native-maps

I have an app in dark theme with react-native-maps. When the map component is rendering the first white preview from google is appearing for a few mili seconds. If the app theme in white it is ok, but on the dark theme the flicker is happening. Can you tell me please how can I change background color of google map preview?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use MapView `userInterfaceStyle` property with `'light' | 'dark'` or create a custom map styling like in description https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#customizing-the-map-style

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but userInterfaceStyle and customMapStyle is not solving my problem. Google map preview is still white

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3416 probably you can use `onMapReady` and wait until tiles would be fully loaded and animate this transition like in the disscusion

Comment: Thats a good decision. Thank you so much Kirill!

Answer (score 3):

use custom style to `mapView` to change light background to dark:

```
  const mapCustomStyle = [ { "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#242f3e" } ] }, { "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#746855" } ] }, { "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#242f3e" } ] }, { "featureType": "administrative.locality", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d59563" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d59563" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#263c3f" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#6b9a76" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#38414e" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#212a37" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#9ca5b3" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#746855" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#1f2835" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#f3d19c" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#2f3948" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d59563" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#17263c" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#515c6d" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#17263c" } ] } ]
```

and Finally in `mapView`:

```
  use customMapStyle= {mapCustomStyle}
```

I have generated the above code from this [site](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).